# Can I use the same preview link for the different file types in Google Drive API?

Tags: google-drive-api

I want to make a preview link to the Google Drive file in my application. A file could be anything eg. Google Docs file, image, pdf etc. I'm using Google Drive API (Files.get).

I found out that thumbnailLink shows images and pdf in "preview" window as an image, but is not enough for pdf files, I want to scroll down the file.

I have used this link https://drive.google.com/file/d/{fileid}/preview in my code and it works with pdf and images. 
And it also shows my Google Docs content (the first version of it). But when I update a Google Docs file, links like https://drive.google.com/file/d/{fileid}/preview doesn't show updated content, it only shows the old content. When I click the preview link, I see a quick flash of the updated content and then it shows the old content. I would like to have the updated content.

Is it possible to use that preview link with Google Docs file too?
Or should I always use EmbedLink with Google Docs file? It still works well.

I'm just wondering what is the right way to do it? And scrolling is the thing, I don't want just images of the files.

Answer (score 1):

The `/preview` URL is not a part of the API and not supported or guaranteed to work in the future. We recommend you only use the links returned by the API, such as the `embedLink` you mentioned.